# Avoid using initialiser list for custom classes

Tags: c++

I've been trying to google this for ages without success, so I'd really appreciate your help!

I use a custom class as a private variable:

```
private:
Location SWCorner;
Location NECorner;
```

In the constructor for the class containing the Location object, I have to give it a value in the initialiser list:

```
Territory::Territory(Location InitialPosition) : NECorner(InitialPosition), SWCorner(InitialPosition) {

  this->NECorner = Location(InitialPosition.getX() + 1, InitialPosition.getY() + 1);
  this->SWCorner = Location(InitialPosition.getX() - 1, InitialPosition.getY() - 1);

}
```

As you can see, what I'm doing is I'm initialising it to some value, and then immediately reassigning the value. This seems ugly to me. I'd really like to do:

```
Territory::Territory(Location InitialPosition) {

  this->NECorner = Location(InitialPosition.getX() + 1, InitialPosition.getY() + 1);
  this->SWCorner = Location(InitialPosition.getX() - 1, InitialPosition.getY() - 1);

}
```

But this throws an error (No matching function call for Location()).

I guess there are two solutions:

1. My inelegant one
2. Specifying a default constructor for Location()

However, I don't really like the second one either since I don't really want to come up with a "default location".

I guess what I'm asking is: is there a third solution I do not know of? Am I overlooking something?

Thanks and all the best!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace this:

```
Territory::Territory(Location InitialPosition) : NECorner(InitialPosition), SWCorner(InitialPosition) {

  this->NECorner = Location(InitialPosition.getX() + 1, InitialPosition.getY() + 1);
  this->SWCorner = Location(InitialPosition.getX() - 1, InitialPosition.getY() - 1);

}
```

with this:

```
Territory::Territory( Location const& initialPosition)
    : NECorner( InitialPosition.getX() + 1, , InitialPosition.getY() + 1)
    , SWCorner( InitialPosition.getX() - 1, InitialPosition.getY() - 1 )
{}
```

---

About style:

If you control the source code for class `Location`, I recommend also removing the Java-like `get` prefixes which are just visual noise in C++. E.g., think `getSin`. You would be seriously surprised if a standard library function were named `getSin`.

Also, I recommend using different naming conventions for types and instances.

Finally, it's very non-idiomatic to use `this->` prefixing. Alternatives include a `my` or `m` prefix for member variables, or a `_` suffix, as used in e.g. Boost library code.

Comment: Yep, you've found me out -- I learnt Java before C++! :) Thanks for the solution and also the suggestions regarding style, I'll look for some guides.

Comment: @noctiulux: There's a style guide book by Andrei Alexandrescu and Herb Sutter. Herb is the chair of the international standardization committee for C++, Andrei is the template expert. As far as I know the only dubious advice in that book is about `reinterpret_cast`, based on an academic problem with the then current standard C++03. Possibly it's been corrected. Anyway it won't make you do anything seriously bad. I think, based on what others have been saying, that it's the best C++ style guide around. Does cost money. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, sounds good -- I'll look it up!

Follow up question though: can I put multiple statements after the colon? E.g. define variables, etc. etc.?

Comment: @noctilux no.  You can just initialize your members.  And the initialization happens in the order they where declared in the class, not the order you type them here (ie, do it in the same order as the class to reduce surprise).

Comment: OK, thanks. That also clears up my reordering warning! I suppose I will have to specify default constructors if I want to do more than one line of processing before setting the variables, then. A bit of a pain, but never mind!

Answer (score 2):

Go like this:

```
Territory::Territory(Location InitialPosition) :
NECorner(InitialPosition.getX() + 1, InitialPosition.getY() + 1),
SWCorner(InitialPosition.getX() - 1, InitialPosition.getY() - 1) {
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer -- you answered the question, too, but the other answer gave more info, so I chose that in the end. Sorry about that!

Comment: @noctilux No problem at all, glad your question was answered :)